Spring SimpleBroker and strange stomp Connected message
I'm working with Spring 6.0.9 and Stomp.
If I use RabbitMq as external Broker, the Stomp "CONNECTED" message looks like this:
   message
     (org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage<T>) GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=OTHER, stompCommand=CONNECTED, nativeHeaders={server=[RabbitMQ/3.12.0], session=[session-bEEGX4Wp-FFsjqxKdCcHuA], heart-beat=[10000,10000], version=[1.1]}, simpSessionId=e1e66ab1-2c15-379e-56f4-ff8cc42c63f9}]

But if I use Spring SimpleBroker, it looks like this:
message
     (org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage<T>) GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT_ACK, simpConnectMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT, stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={accept-version=[1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpHeartbeat=[J@3fdb5ed7, simpSessionId=23f60a25-6cf6-bbdc-53c3-a3c2c8632740}], simpSessionId=23f60a25-6cf6-bbdc-53c3-a3c2c8632740}]

I discover it working with a ChannelInterceptor that adds a custom header on connected msg, infact StompHeaderAccessor.wrap well works on RabbitMQ message but doesn't work for Spring SimpleBroker.
Why they look so different?
How can I add a custom header to Connected msg of Spring SimpleBroker?
